# Move view up and down with limitations

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got this code, that allows the user to drag up a view to a certain extent:

```
  func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)

    print("the translation x:\(translation.x) & y:\(recognizer.view?.frame.minY)")

    if(recognizer.view?.frame.minY > -268)
    {
        if let view = recognizer.view {

            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x,
                y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }


}
```

Now, I would also like to let the user drag down the view, to a certain extent.
How can I change the function to let him to do that?

Currently, I can move the view up and, when he reaches a certain height, it stops and can't be moved anymore in any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your condition of entering the part of code which handles moving the center. It could look like this (Obj-C snippet):

```
if(recognizer.view.frame.origin.y <= 256 && recognizer.view.frame.origin.y >= 0) {
  // logic to move center
}
```

This checks the view position in both directions.

---

EDIT:

To move the view after it went outside of the specified range, you can always check if the new center point is inside that range. Eg.

```
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
if (newCenter.y > 256) {
    newCenter.y = 256;
}
if (newCenter.y < 0) {
    newCenter.y = 0;
}
```

This is a very simple, and maybe not very clever solution, but it should work as the view will not be able to leave the range.

Comment: it didn't work, it's making me move the view of a very small amount

Comment: Try changing the 0 and 256 values to some others, it all depends on where your view is on screen.

Comment: By doing so, when the view stops because it reached the maximum height, it can never moved anymore, since origin.y will always remain the same